# Filter in one column then filter occurences of a word

Tags: r

How would I count the number of occurences after I filter a dataset in regards to one column (e.g "Variant" column for "A/T") then subsequently filter in another column for words containing a particular word(e.g "SEQ" column for "G[A]C")?

Ive tried the following but received an error:

```
length(which(mydata$VARIANT =="A/T") & grep(length("G[A]A", mydata$SEQ)))
```

Checking in excel, filtering for just 'A/T' reveals 9 then there are 2 containing 'G[A]C'

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on that example.  The trouble here is `&` operator connecting two numeric index.  I think you need `sum(mydata$VARIANT == "A/T" & grepl("G[A]A", mydata$SEQ, fixed = TRUE))`

Comment: That works perfectly fine. Its 6am here, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `&`, we need logical vectors.  So, instead of `grep`, it should be `grepl`

```
sum(mydata$VARIANT == "A/T" & grepl("G[A]A", mydata$SEQ, fixed = TRUE))
```